# Doxygen: Refer to members in another group

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I have a C++ project where we use Doxygen to document our code. The documentation for it is split in a main group and a subgroup. What I've noticed is that the automatic link generation does not look in other groups than the current one. Thus, my documentation in the subgroup cannot link to members (in this case, a class) in the main group.

It would have assumed a subgroup could at least reference to members in its "parent group".

**Is there anyway to implicitly refer to a member in another group?** Similar to namespaces or packages.

If not, are there any way to explicitly link the member's documentation page? Is a bug prone URL the only way?

---

I've tried

- `` `tSomeClass` ``,
- `` `group_main::tSomeClass` ``,
- `` `group_main\tSomeClass` ``,
- `` `\ref tSomeClass` ``,
- `` `\ref group_main\tSomeClass` ``,
- `` `\ref group_main::tSomeClass` ``,

---

Minimal example:

##### tSomeClass.hpp

```
/// \ingroup group_main
class tSomeClass {};
```

##### main.dox

```
\defgroup   group_main Main Group Documentation
\addtogroup group_main

Blabla...
```

##### sub.dox

```
\ingroup    group_main
\defgroup   group_sub  Sub Group Documentation
\addtogroup group_sub  

Some text referring to the `tSomeClass` type, fails to link to it.
```

---

##### Edit:

Worth noting, is that I have used this sub-grouping to get a nice hierarchy of documentation pages in the modules overview in the generated html-file. We have yet not used `pages` and I want my documentation to end up with the existing one. It is using groups/`modules`.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Any special settings (`doxygen -x`)?

Comment: v1.8.13. The `-x` option flag is not recognized for me. What kind of special settings are you referring to? There are a bunch of behavior and path options set for Doxygen, are those the special settings you ask about?

Comment: The 1.8.13 version is a bit older (December 2016) and doesn't have some nice features of the newer version. I refer to the settings in the Doxyfile that are different from the default settings. With the 1.8.13 version and a default Doxyfile I already see some links with the examples you gave (after removing the quotes there. With the current version I also see some links. What is missing here?

Comment: What quotes? The backticks?

Comment: Yes the backticks.

Comment: It did not help me, unfortunately. Maybe it is a bug in this version? The version is however something that is out of my hands, since another team controls that.

Comment: Well, like I wrote, I do see also links with the 1.8.13 version (on the page html/group__group__sub.html), so maybe you could publish what you see and which warning messages you get.

Comment: You wrote: The version is however something that is out of my hands, since another team controls that. I would say try to perused the hat team to install a newer version maybe parallel to the 1.8.13 version. You can also easily install a doxygen version locally (see the download page on the doxygen web site).

Comment: The documentation is a part of a CI pipeline, in which a local build would not help. However, I will try to get a newer version going if it is that old. We try to use up to date software in other places.

Comment: (I will update with some pictures in the morning, whe I can access the work computer again)